# Error when using static methods

Tags: c++, visual-c++, system.drawing, visual-c++-2012

I am trying to modify the matrix "matriz" from other classes when a certain sprite moves the screen. The errors I get are "Juego is not a class or namespace" and "isVacio, isRompible, etc identifier not found". I tried doing this in a separate class called "Utilidades" but still got the same errors when trying to call the methods. I don't know what to do.

This is the code that has the error(class "Bomba"):

```
    if (Juego::isVacio(x - 35, y)){ /*Sprite explosion*/}
if (Juego::isVacio(x + 35, y)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (Juego::isVacio(x, y + 35)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (Juego::isVacio(x, y - 35)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (x - 35 < 35 || x + 35 > gr->VisibleClipBounds.Width - 35 || Juego::isBloque(x + 35, y) || Juego::isBloque(x - 35, y)){}
if (y - 35 < 35 || y + 35 > gr->VisibleClipBounds.Height - 35 || Juego::isBloque(x, y + 35) || Juego::isBloque(x, y - 35)){}
if (Juego::Juego::isRompible(x - 35, y)){ Juego::romperBloque(x - 35, y, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x + 35, y)){ Juego::romperBloque(x + 35, y, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x, y + 35)){ Juego::romperBloque(x, y + 35, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x, y - 35)){ Juego::romperBloque(x, y - 35, gr); }
//2bloques
if (Juego::isVacio(x - 70, y)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (Juego::isVacio(x + 70, y)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (Juego::isVacio(x, y + 70)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (Juego::isVacio(x, y - 70)){/*Sprite explosion*/ }
if (x - 70 < 35 || x + 70 > gr->VisibleClipBounds.Width - 35 || Juego::isBloque(x + 70, y) || Juego::isBloque(x - 70, y)){}
if (y - 70 < 35 || y + 70 > gr->VisibleClipBounds.Height - 35 || Juego::isBloque(x, y + 70) || Juego::isBloque(x, y - 70)){}
if (Juego::isRompible(x - 70, y)){ Juego::romperBloque(x - 70, y, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x + 70, y)){ Juego::romperBloque(x + 70, y, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x, y + 70)){ Juego::romperBloque(x, y + 70, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x, y - 70)){ Juego::romperBloque(x, y - 70, gr); }
//3bloques
if (Juego::isVacio(x - 105, y)){}
if (Juego::isVacio(x +105, y)){}
if (Juego::isVacio(x, y + 105)){}
if (Juego::isVacio(x, y - 105)){}
if (x - 105 < 35 || x + 105 > gr->VisibleClipBounds.Width - 35 || Juego::isBloque(x + 105, y) || Juego::isBloque(x-105, y)){}
if (y - 105 < 35 || y + 105 > gr->VisibleClipBounds.Height - 35 || Juego::isBloque(x, y + 105) || Juego::isBloque(x, y - 105)){}
if (Juego::isRompible(x - 105, y)){ Juego::romperBloque(x - 105, y, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x + 105, y)){ Juego::romperBloque(x + 105, y, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x, y + 105)){ Juego::romperBloque(x, y + 105, gr); }
if (Juego::isRompible(x, y - 105)){ Juego::romperBloque(x, y - 105, gr); }
```

This is the class Juego:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "Jugador.h"
#include "Enemigo.h"
#include "Bomba.h"


using namespace std;


class Juego
{
    int nivel;
    EntidadViva* objJugador;
    //Enemigo* objEnemigo;
public:
    static bool isBloque(int px, int py);
    static bool isRompible(int px, int py);
    static bool isBomba(int px, int py);
    static bool isVacio(int px, int py);
    static void romperBloque(int px, int py, Graphics^ gr);
    static int ** matriz;
    static std::vector<Bomba*> bombas;
    ~Juego(void);
    Juego(void);
    void setDireccion_Jugador(Direccion dir);
    void Crear_Enemigo(int px, int py);
    void Crear_Jugador(int px, int py);
    void Mover_Entidades(Graphics^ gr);
    void Perseguir();
    Jugador* getJugador();
    int getNivel();
    void setNivel(int n);
    void cargarMatriz();
    void addBomba(Bomba* b);
    Point getPrimeraPosicionJugador();
};
/*---------------------Utilidades---------------*/
        //Check de bloque//
bool Juego::isBloque(int px, int py)
{
    if (matriz[px][py] == 0 || matriz[px][py] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
     // Check de rompible//
bool Juego::isRompible(int px, int py)
{
    if (matriz[px][py] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
    // Check de bomba//
bool Juego::isBomba(int px, int py)
{
    for each(Bomba* bmb in bombas)
    {
        if (bmb->getX() == px && bmb->getY() == py)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

        //Rompe un bloque rompible//
void Juego::romperBloque(int px, int py, Graphics^ gr)
{
    matriz[px][py] = 3;
    //Animacion de explosion del bloque

}
    // Check de Vacio//
bool Juego::isVacio(int px, int py)
{
    if (matriz[px][py] == 3){ return true; }
    else{ return false; }
}

void Juego::addBomba(Bomba* b)
{
    bombas.push_back(b);
}
void Juego::cargarMatriz()
{
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("Level1.txt");


    matriz = new int *[23];

    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        matriz[i] = new int[23];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
        {
            fin >> matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void Juego::setNivel(int n){ nivel = n; }
int Juego::getNivel(){ return nivel; }
Juego::~Juego(void)
{
    delete objJugador;
    //delete objEnemigo;
}
Jugador* Juego::getJugador(){ return (Jugador*)objJugador; }
Juego::Juego(void)
{
    nivel = 1;
    cargarMatriz();
    //Crear_Enemigo(10, 10);
    Point p = this->getPrimeraPosicionJugador();
    Crear_Jugador(50, 50);
}
void Juego::setDireccion_Jugador(Direccion dir)
{
    objJugador->setMovimiento(dir);
    switch (dir)
    {
    case ABAJO:
        objJugador->setDx(0); objJugador->setDy(5);
        break;
    case ARRIBA:
        objJugador->setDx(0); objJugador->setDy(-5);
        break;
    case DERECHA:
        objJugador->setDx(5); objJugador->setDy(0);
        break;
    case IZQUIERDA:
        objJugador->setDx(-5); objJugador->setDy(0);
        break;
    }
}
Point Juego::getPrimeraPosicionJugador()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 23; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 23; y++)
        {
            if (matriz[x][y == 5])
            {
                return Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
void Juego::Crear_Jugador(int px, int py)
{
    objJugador = new Jugador(px, py);
}
void Juego::Crear_Enemigo(int px, int py)
{
    //objEnemigo = new Enemigo(px, py);
}
void Juego::Mover_Entidades(Graphics^ gr)
{
    //((Enemigo*)objEnemigo)->Mover(gr);
    ((Jugador*)objJugador)->Mover(gr);
}
```

Comment: `matriz[x][y == 5]` doesn't seem right…

Comment: That's just a typo. The error is that I cannot access this methods from another class even though I included it and the methods are static and public.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but seems really trivial:
You need to split Juego code: class declaration in a Juego.hpp file, member implementation in a Juego.cpp file including previous one.

And then #include your Juego.hpp in files requiring to "know" Juego.

The code you posted for Juego class seems to be in a single file (declaration & implementation), so it seems unlikely you did #include it in another file (and cannot #include it in more than one file, it would give a linker error)

Comment: As far as I know defining methods/functions outside the class in the header file is the same ass defining the Header file declarations in a CPP file.

Comment: Yes, but you want your Bomba class to know about Juego class in order to write the code you wrote.
so your Bomba,cpp (or .h) must include the file containing Juego class declaration, but not class implementation.
That's (one of) the reason for using the cpp & header files, and not only cpp ones